C# Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch MatchAll() Issue
I am trying to bring back all the documents in an index using c#.
I am using Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch library as NEST is depreciating.
I am trying to get all the documents from an index into a dictionary.
I cannot seem to retrieve the documents. I cannot be explicit in the field names because they are dynamic.
Intellisense in VS shows that MatchAll is there but I cannot see what it should look like and I'm having trouble finding any documentation showing MatchAll being used.
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(s => s
    .Index("user-field-mappings")
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll())
);

I get an error stating No overload for method MatchAll takes 0 arguments.
So I modified to this
var searchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(s => s
    .Index("user-field-mappings")
    .Query(q => q.MatchAll(m => m))
);


That results in Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await and new obj expresions can be used as a statement.

Probably something like m => new MatchAllQuery()

This is what ended up working.
var mappingSearchResponse = await _elasticClient.SearchAsync<Dictionary<string, object>>(s => s
.Index(mappingIndexName)
.Query(new Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch.QueryDsl.MatchAllQuery())

);

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
